# Using a wildcard SSL with a CNAME pointing to EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cname

I have a CNAME on my domain pointing to an Amazon EC2 instance. I would like to utilize my wildcard SSL certificate to secure this connection - https://secure.mydomain.com would point to the EC2 instance.

Is such a thing possible? Unfortunately I am fairly new to both SSL certificates and EC2 instances. Is this where Route 53 might come into play?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to put the cert on an elastic load balancer, and then point that to your instance. This makes it easier to scale, and you don't have to worry about elastic IP's or any extra configuration when rolling out new instances.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin and user602525 for pointing me in the direction of ELB! Set up was painless and now everything is working great!

Answer (score 1):

Yea you can do this. You just need the cert on your Ec2 instance, make sure port 443 is open in your security group. And make sure whatever web server you're using is configured properly for SSL.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting there bit by bit, I have successfully opened Port 443 on the instance and tomorrow will tackle trying to install the SSL cert. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache 2, if you can offer any guidance on installing the cert I'd appreciate it! Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to save yourself the hassle of configuring Apache. You can instead, set up an elastic load balancer and have it point to your EC2 instance - There is a spot to upload your cert in the load balancer set up.

Comment: There is an additional cost to ELB though - http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/